# ValueError in portfolio vol calculation

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to calculate portfolio vol in python and this is my code, but it's returning error

```
ValueError: shapes (3,3) and (1,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

My code is below

```
portfolio_vol = np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T,np.dot(covariance.values*252,weights)))
```

The covariance is a df and the weights is an array of 3 values in a row
Does anyone know why the error is coming up? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like what you want is rather `np.sqrt(np.dot(weights,np.dot(covariance.values*252,weights.T)))`. Does `weights.shape` return `(1, 3)` ? Also, do you want `portfolio_vol` to be scalar ?

Comment: You're right, that worked. Thank you Yes, I want it to be scalar.